# X.PagedList.Mvc com Core e Bootstrap 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, .net-core

Como utilizar o `X.PagedList.Mvc` com `Core` e `Bootstrap 4.0`, e assim criar uma paginação completa automática.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hoje venho trazer, uma forma de utilizar o `X.PagedList.Mvc` com `Core`e `Bootstrap 4.0`:

Primeiramente temos que baixar o X.PagedList.Mvc.Core via NuGet.

Na `VIEW` Utilizaremos:

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
@model X.PagedList.StaticPagedList<"Seu Model">
```

E aqui está o truque:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: right">
        Página @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) de @Model.PageCount
    </div>

    <div class="justify-content-center">
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagina => Url.Action("Index", new { search = ViewBag.Busca, pagina }), new PagedListRenderOptions { FunctionToTransformEachPageLink = (liTag, aTag) => { aTag.Attributes.Add("class", "page-link".ToString()); return aTag; }, LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-item" }, UlElementClasses = new[] { "pagination  justify-content-center" } })
    </div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma o `@Html.PagedListPager`, criará as novas classes que são necessárias para o Bootstrap 4.0.

E para finalizar, é so retornar o model com todos os dados necessários para View atráves do `Controller`.

Até mais e um abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Extendendo a resposta do @Matheus, para o **ASP .NET Framework** funcionar corretamente é preciso retornar a `liTag` em vez da `aTag` da função `FunctionToTransformEachPageLink`, pois se não a lista é renderizada em `<li>`s, somente `<a>`s, ficando assim:

```
<div>Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount</div>

@Html.PagedListPager(
    Model,
    page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }),
    new PagedListRenderOptions {
        FunctionToTransformEachPageLink = (liTag, aTag) =>
        {
            aTag.Attributes.Add("class", "page-link");
            liTag.InnerHtml = aTag.ToString();
            return liTag;
        },
        LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-item" },
        UlElementClasses = new[] { "pagination justify-content-center" } }
)
```

A utilização da model também fica um pouquinho diferente:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<"Seu Model">
@using PagedList.Mvc
```

Tendo um resultado aproximado à este:

[image: Preview dos itens de paginação]